# react axios does not see php file path

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax, axios

I want to do `ajax` call from react to my `php`. Here is my code:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import ConsultForm from "./ConsultForm/ConsultForm";
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import store from "./store/index";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";


function App(props) {
  const submitConsult = props => {
    props.preventDefault()
    console.log("Submit form", props)
    axios.post('../server/send.php', {

    })
    .then(responce => {
      alert("Send successfully")
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <ConsultForm onSubmit={submitConsult} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**My project folder**

```
my-project|
          | - server-|
                     |-send.php
          
          | - src  - |
                     |-App.js
```

**Error***

`POST http://localhost:3000/server/send.php 404 (Not Found)`

How should I specify my axios ajax call path?

Comment: assuming `3000` is your node port and 80 is the php server port. Use full url: `http://localhost/MY_APP_FOLDER/server/send.php` in your ajax call

Comment: @AndréWalker That is right. But now I encountered another error `POST http://localhost/MY_APP_FOLDER/server/send.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, it means that I should run PHP server or something?

Comment: your PHP server is probably already running. Sorry by my confusion, but you replaced the `MY_APP_FOLDER` by the actual name of your directory? basically you need use the same address tht you use in your browser.

Comment: @AndréWalker yes, I wrote here `MY_APP_FOLDER` just for an example of my real folder name, your solution worked great and if you want you can write it as an answer, I will accept it. But if you don't mind - could you also help me a little with `connection refused` error after `ajax` call?

Comment: you checked if your server is already running? which server you use ? apache, nginx, ...

Comment: @AndréWalker I just run `npm start` and that's all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228324/discussion-between-andre-walker-and-whoami).